# Angular.js: Is there any disadvantage of hash in url with respect to SEO?

Tags: angularjs, seo, search-engine

I am making a website using AngularJS, I am curious to know that is there any disadvantage of hash in url with respect to seo ?

e.g. http://www.website.com/#about-us

I'll appreciate any contribution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we go back to the basics, HASH # means a DIV ID in your HTML, and to talk in more details Google ignores anything after the HASH.

Example, this page www.mydomain.com is similar to www.mydomain.com/#about-us

This is an advanced technique some marketers are using it to track their campaign without using parameters like UTMs to avoid content duplication.

To make sure your page is loading without any errors, try to disable the JS from your browsers using "Web Developer Tool" and then load your page, i think you will get a white page without content and this is the way Google and most of the search engines see your pages.

Also there is another way to test it by going to Search Console "Webmaster tool" and use fetch as Google, here you will see exactly how Google view your page.